# Why is my C++ symbol name different from the libtorrent library I'm linking to and does this cause linking to fail?

Tags: c++, unresolved-external, name-mangling, libtorrent

I'm trying to link a simple C++ program to `libtorrent`:

```cpp
#include <libtorrent/add_torrent_params.hpp>
#include <libtorrent/magnet_uri.hpp>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    lt::add_torrent_params atp = lt::parse_magnet_uri(argv[1]);
}
```

I invoke `cl.exe` on the command line and it tells me that I have unresolved external symbols:

```
>cl /EHsc /Fefoo.exe /I<snip>\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include main.cpp torrent-rasterbar.lib /link /LIBPATH:<snip>\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31937 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.34.31937.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:foo.exe
/LIBPATH:C:\Users\rages\code\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\lib
main.obj
torrent-rasterbar.lib
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall libtorrent::add_torrent_params::~add_torrent_params(void)" (??1add_torrent_params@libtorrent@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct libtorrent::add_torrent_params __cdecl libtorrent::parse_magnet_uri(class boost::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >)" (?parse_magnet_uri@libtorrent@@YA?AUadd_torrent_params@1@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@boost@@@Z) referenced in function _main
foo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Running `dumpbin /exports` on `torrent-rasterbar.lib` and looking for the `add_torrent_params` symbol shows me this:

```
??1add_torrent_params@v2@libtorrent@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall libtorrent::v2::add_torrent_params::~add_torrent_params(void))
```

This is very different from what the compiler is complaining about. I suspect this is what's causing the linker to fail, but I'm not quite sure what I need to do differently to make it work. How do I get my compiler and the library to agree on the symbol names?

Comment: the dump looks like you have a v2 library, but hte compiler seems to look for an older version. Maybe you forgot some #define to set the right version to use? Are you using the matching headers for your library?

Comment: The symbols in the library are decorated with a version number "v2" while the symbols expected by the compiler are not decorated. To resolve this, you can add the following line of code before the inclusion of the libtorrent headers:

#define BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION

This line disables the version decoration of symbols in the libtorrent library. You may also need to add the BOOST library to your linker input if you are not already doing so.

Comment: The compiler is showing the demangled symbols. Tools, like dumpbin, show the mangled symbols. I feel a bit lazy right now, someone else will need to find the appropriate dupe.

Comment: @OyvindAndersson Thanks for the suggestion. That seems to have added more unresolved externals to boost (which I can probably resolve by passing boost to the linker), but the original two unresolved symbols are still reported as errors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually both are showing both mangled and demangled symbols just in a different order, the symbols are actually different

Comment: @Ragesh The issue with the unresolved externals may be due to the fact that the library you are linking with is not built with the same runtime library as your program?

Comment: @OyvindAndersson That is possible. I installed libtorrent using `vcpkg`, which appears to have built it with `cmake`, but it's not clear to me exactly what it does under the covers. If this is the issue, does it mean I need to build my app with cmake as well? My apologies if these are fundamentally basic questions; this is the first time I'm trying C++ in years and I'm lost :)

Comment: Due to historical reasons, `int main(int argc, char const* argv[])` should be `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

Comment: @Ragesh No you don't necessarily have to compile with CMake, you can use Visual C++ compiler and buildsystem. You can specify the runtime library you want to use by the switches "/MD: DLL" or "/MT: Static". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170

Comment: @OyvindAndersson I asked `vcpkg` to give me a shared DLL (`x86-windows`), not `x86-windows-static`, so I think my runtime should be `/MD`, but it doesn't seem to help. I tried `/MT` as well just for kicks, but the symbols are all still mismatched the same as before.

I just re-read your comment about BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION. The issue is that libtorrent already has `v2` being exported, so I think I need something that lets me add the `v2` decoration at my end rather than remove it, right?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using old headers  (from v1) `add_torrent_params.hpp`, check that all your headers are updated from the latest V2 libtorrent source

Comment: @user20716902 The headers are what `vcpkg` pulled when it built 2.0.8, so I am assuming they are correct.

Comment: @Ragesh, in that case have you enabled c++14, as libtorrent v2 requires it

Comment: @user20716902 I just tried adding `/std:c++14` now and it didn't help. I feel like maybe I'm missing something about how `vcpkg` builds libtorrent.

Comment: @Ragesh, I've been doing some research on this, I think you need to `#include "libtorrent/fwd.hpp”` This add the v2 namespace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251744/discussion-between-ragesh-and-user20716902).

Comment: Thanks everyone for chipping in! I finally figured out which missing define was causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a missing define. The libtorrent build page is very clear about this:

> A common mistake when building and linking against libtorrent is to build with one set of configuration options (#defines) and link against it using a different set of configuration options. Since libtorrent has some code in header files, that code will not be compatible with the built library if they see different configurations.
>
> Always make sure that the same TORRENT_* and BOOST_* macros are defined when you link against libtorrent as when you build it. The simplest way to see the full list of macros defined is to build libtorrent with -n -a switches added to b2 command line, which output all compiler switches.

So I began investigating how `vcpkg` was building libtorrent. I was able to find some output at `$VCPKG_DIR/buildtrees/libtorrent/install-x64-windows-rel-out.log` which showed me all the flags that it was passing to `cl` for each file. Sure enough, passing every single flag there got my code to compile.

By a process of elimination, I found that `TORRENT_NO_DEPRECATE` is the magic sauce that makes it work. Here's the bare minimum you need to get it to compile:

```
> cl -DTORRENT_NO_DEPRECATE /nologo /EHsc /Fefoo.exe /IE:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include main.cpp torrent-rasterbar.lib /link /LIBPATH:E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib main.cpp
```

Please note this is just for illustrating a solution to the specific issue of mismatched symbols. You should probably use the full set of defines found in the `vcpkg` log to make sure there are no surprises down the road from other headers.